# Identity Server 4, Quickstart #1: Am I supposed to Apis => vs what the documentation says?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm having a problem with the first Quickstart example.  The [Documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) states:

> Find the Config.cs file you can find a method called GetApiResources,
>   define the API as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
    };
}
```

but the example code provided has this:

```
        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis =>
            new ApiResource[] 
            { };
```

Am I supposed to use the Apis Expression Body Member(?).

Comment: Where did you get the sample code? The documentation links to [this repository](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/1_ClientCredentials/src/IdentityServer/Config.cs#L20), which looks the same, besides the name: GetApiResources => GetApis.

Comment: I followed the "Quickstart" [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html).  The code comes from the IdentityServer4.Templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array` types are reference types derived from the abstract base type Array. Since this type implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` , you can use :

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis =>
    new ApiResource[] 
    {new ApiResource("api1", "My API")};
```

And use like: `.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)`

Or :

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
    };
}
```

And use like :  `.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())`